# Assign text to a line of a multi-line UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, string, uilabel

UILabel's text is assigned as a whole. If there is a multi-line label is there a way to assign a string of text to a specific line of that label.

So that instead of doing `myLabel.text = "A very long line...."` can I do something like `myLabel.text.line[0] /*(or [1] or whatever)*/ = "One line from my whole string"`?

Comment: That is not possible... But can you try to describe what you want to achieve instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add line breaks in your string with "\n"

```
myLabel.text = "A \n very long \n line"
```

Note: Set the label's number of lines to 0, to allow any any number of lines.

```
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create an array of lines and then assign the text to the lines like this:

```
var lines = [String]()
lines.append("Line number 1")
lines.append("Line number n")
```

and then you could do something like this:

```
func setLabelTextForLines(lines:[String]){
    var text = ""
    for line in lines {
        text += line
        text += "\n"
    }

    myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    myLabel.text = text
}
```

So you could have an array called lines and edit it and then call the function to reassign the text:

```
setLabelTextForLines(lines)
lines[0] = "Changed the first line"
setLabelTextForLines(lines)
```